# How to run rake tasks in the background daily without using cron or heroku scheduler?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, rake, scheduler

I want the rake task to do some quick API calls daily at 9AM Eastern.

I thought about wiring an initializer that busywaits until it's 9:01 or something like that but that seems silly.

I know heroku has their own internal scheduler but is it necessary to use for a simple API call?

Answer (score 1):

You're going to have to use some sort of scheduler to run your rake task, be it cron or the heroku scheduler.

Rake is just a specialized build DSL, it's just a language that can run builds or other tasks. It's a program just like any other, and hence can only run when someone tells it to. That someone would be a scheduler like cron.